# $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\pi x\log(x) + \pi x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}$ should not be defined, right?

Tags: calculus, limits

Ok, first of all, here is the limit I'm talking about:

[image]

Now, this may be a stupid question to ask, but I'll still ask it since I'm getting really confused about it and W|A isn't making me feel better.

We all know that the domain of the logarithm function $f(x)=\log_b x~,~b\in\Bbb{R^+}$ is $(0,+\infty)$.

So, shouldn't the two sided limit in the picture be undefined? Because when $x\to 0^-$, we have $\log(x)$ undefined and hence the left hand limit should not exist. Right?

Am I missing something important?

**Note:** For those who don't know, $\log(x)$ is referring to the natural logarithm here, *not* the base $10$ logarithm.

Comment: The logarithm is defined for both positive, negative, and complex variables, only your silly calculus teacher says otherwise...(that was just a joke, she knows the truth too...)

Comment: He firmly states that $\log(x)$ is undefined $\forall x\leq 0$.

Comment: You are using the real natural logarithm - WolframAlpha is using the complex logarithm, which is defined for all nonzero $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Notice that WolframAlpha's graph of the relevant function has a non-zero imaginary part for $x<0$.

Comment: Let me clarify, the logarithm is not analytic, or not well defined at 0.

Comment: @learner It depends on what context you are using, however if we allow the domain and range to both be complex numbers, the logarithm is indeed defined.  We have $z = e^w \Leftrightarrow \text{Log} (z) = w$ for complex numbers $z$ and $w$.  In particular, this definition allows for negative reals or other nonzero complex numbers.  More formally, for $z=a+bi=re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$ and $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi)$ you have $\text{Log} (z) = \ln (r) + i\theta$.  Note that this definition does not allow for $\text{Log}(0)$ since there does not exist any complex number $w$ for which $0=e^w$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of the function $x^x$ for $x$ to $0$ is $1$.

[image]

The limit of $x\ln x$ or $\ln x^x$ is $\ln 1$ or $0$. That's why the expressing $x\ln x+p(x)$, where $p$ is some polynomial, is well behaved.

From your perspective, the limit of $x^x$ should be the mysterious aspect. You can better understand it by considering that the square root is not a differentiable function at $x=0$. Therefore, while $\sqrt 0$ is zero, $\sqrt\varepsilon$ for some tiny $\varepsilon$ is already pretty big. The square root has a large slope at $x=0$, is monotonous, and then equal to $1$ at $x=1$. This is also true for $N$'th square roots. Now consider some large number $N$ and the small value $x=\frac{1}{N}$. The value $x^x=(\frac{1}{N})^\frac{1}{N}$ is the $N$'th root of a tiny number. $x^x$ is some relatively large number between $0$ and $1$. For larger $N$, i.e. closer to $x=0$ and for higher roots, it turns out that $(\frac{1}{N})^\frac{1}{N}$ approaches $1$.

[image]